# Bucle infinito en c no muestra su identificador(PID)

Tags: c

Muy buenas, quiero hacer un programa que primero muestre su pid por pantalla y posteriormente realize un bucle infinito, para así poder matarlo con otro programa que tengo. El problema es que el programa no me muestra por pantalla su pid, simplemente pasa directamente al bucle infinito y no muestra antes el printf. Si alguien sabe como se hace me ayudaría mucho, os dejo aqui el código:

```
int main(){
    int flag=0;
    printf("Soy el proceso con id %i",getpid());
    while(flag==0){
        //Bucle infinito
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Será porque el loop, así como está, no le da opción a que se se ejecuten las instrucciones que imprime en consola. . Pon el printf dentro del loop y o verás o ponle un sleep dentro de loop.

Comment: La escritura no es instantánea, se usa un buffer intermedio para optimizar. Has `fflush( stdout )` después del printf para forzar a vaciar el buffer

Answer (score 1):

Prueba agregando la siguiente línea, escribirás todo lo almacenado en el buffer y luego entrará en bucle.

```
int main(){
    int flag=0;
    printf("Soy el proceso con id %i",getpid());
    fflush(stdout); // Esto.
    while(flag==0){
        //Bucle infinito
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```